# Getting codes from Huffman tree method in Java

Tags: java, huffman-code

I've written code that should be able to return an ArrayList of the codes in my  Huffman Tree. The Code class has a character and its corresponding encoding. In the tree, left edges are designated as 0 and right edges as 1. I use two methods to retrieve the codes.

```
public ArrayList<Code> getCodes() {
        ArrayList<Code> code = new ArrayList<Code>();
        if (root == null) return null;
        traverse(code, root.left, "0");
        traverse(code, root.right, "1");
        return code;
}


private void traverse(ArrayList<Code> code, BinaryTreeNode<Letter> node, String prefix) {
        
    if(node==null){
        code.add(new Code(node.getElement().getLetter(), prefix));
    }
    else if (node.getLeft()!=null){
        traverse(code, node.getLeft(), prefix + "0");
    }
    else if (node.getRight()!=null){
        traverse(code, node.getRight(), prefix + "1");
    }

}
```

But I'm getting incorrect output. It should look like this, displaying all my codes:

> Start
>
> Size of codes is 27
>
> Code [ch= , code=00]
>
> Code [ch=e, code=010]
>
> Code [ch=n, code=0110]
>
> Code [ch=i, code=0111]
>
> Code [ch=b, code=100000]
>
> Code [ch=p, code=100001]
>
> Code [ch=y, code=100010]
>
> Code [ch=g, code=100011]
>
> Code [ch=o, code=1001]
>
> [...]

But instead, I get this:

> Start
>
> Size of codes is 0

It doesn't seem like my codes/characters/anything are being saved to my ArrayList. Any suggestions on what could be going wrong?

Comment: How do you build the `root` structure (easier to debug if we have your data)? Maybe add ... `else System.out.println("Unexpected");` in the end of the traverse method. I suspect the execution 'falls out' there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

- If `getLeft` is not `null`, traverse will not investigate `getRight`
- `traverse` does recursion only when `getLeft` or `getRight` are not null. That means you never send `null` to the `traverse` method, but you only add results to the `code` array if `null` is sent to the traverse method (ie never).

The traverse method should probably be:

```
if(node==null){
    code.add(new Code(node.getElement().getLetter(), prefix));
} else {
    traverse(code, node.getLeft(), prefix + "0");
    traverse(code, node.getRight(), prefix + "1");
}
```

You can also make the code slightly fancier (and shorter) by starting with `traverse(code, root, "");` (instead of `traverse(...left)` and `traverse(...right)`)

Comment: When I changed my code to the above, I hit a NullPointerException at the following lines of code:

code.add(new Code(node.getElement().getLetter(), prefix)); and

traverse(code, root.left, "0");